# My implementation of the grid traveller problem only works for small grids

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am attempting this problem at 38:39 into this free code camp video: https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk?t=2361

The question is as follows:

> Say that you are a traveller on a 2D grid. You begin in the top
> left corner and and your goal is to travel to the bottom right corner.
> You may only move down or right.
>
> In how many ways can you travel to the to the goal on a grid with
> dimensions m*n
>
> Write a function GridTraveller(m,n) that calculates this.

My attempt gives the correct answer for everything except the 18 by 18 grid, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


struct grid {
  unsigned long long int x,y;
  grid(unsigned long long int x_c, unsigned long long  int y_c):x(x_c),y(y_c){};

 bool operator< (const grid& rhs) const {
    return (x + y < rhs.x+rhs.y);

}
};



unsigned long long int grd_traveller(grid grd, std::map <grid,unsigned long long int> &mem){
  if (mem.count(grd) != 0){
    return mem[grd];
  }
  else if (grd.x ==1 || grd.y ==1){
    return 1;
  }

  else if (grd.x==0 || grd.y ==0){
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    grid iter1(grd.x-1,grd.y);
    grid iter2(grd.x,grd.y-1);

    unsigned long long int answer =  grd_traveller(iter1,mem) + grd_traveller(iter2,mem);
    mem[grd] = answer;
    return answer;
  }
}



int main(){
  std::map <grid,unsigned long long int> memory;
  std::cout << std::to_string(grd_traveller(grid(1,1),memory))<<"\n"; // Should give 1 and does
  std::cout << std::to_string(grd_traveller(grid(2,3),memory))<<"\n"; // Should give 3 and does
  std::cout << std::to_string(grd_traveller(grid(3,2),memory))<<"\n"; // Should give 3 and does
  std::cout << std::to_string(grd_traveller(grid(3,3),memory))<<"\n"; // Should give 6 and does
  std::map <grid,unsigned long long int> memory2;
  std::cout << grd_traveller(grid(18,18),memory2)<<"\n"; // Should give 2333606220, but doesn't 

}
```

At first I thought it might be memory issues so I increased everything to an unsigned long long int but that has not fixed it. What is even stranger is that for the 18 by 18 grid I get a different answer if I use the first map `memory` or the second map `memory2`. This is very weird and I am at a loss as to what is causing this behaviour. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Jeffrey I am aware that this is the technique that should be used. I am using memoization, just for some reason it is not working for very large grids.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, had missed it in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your comparison operator overload:

```cpp
x + y < rhs.x+rhs.y
```

This check is not enough since it just compares the sum of coordinates. You should write one that checks the coordinates in a certain order:

```cpp
x < rhs.x || x == rhs.x && y < rhs.y
```

Otherwise, for example, grids with coordinates (1, 5) and (2, 4) are considered to be equal by the `std::map` container since `1 + 5 == 2 + 4`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll unsigned long long

//memoization.

ll grid(ll x, ll y) {
    static map<pair<ll, ll>, ll>memo;
    if (x == 0 || y == 0) return 0;
    if (x == 1 && y == 1) return 1;
    if (memo.count(make_pair(x, y)) > 0) return memo[make_pair(x, y)];
    memo[make_pair(x, y)] = grid(x - 1, y) + grid(x, y - 1);
    return memo[make_pair(x, y)];
    
}



int main() {
    cout << grid(18, 18);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please don't use or recommend `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow.